# Troubles styling my bottom positioned popover arrow

Tags: bootstrap-4, popover, arrows

I am trying to style my popover arrow.

I tried many options found online, but the closest I got to it was like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5kPe.png)

my code:

```
    <img src="images/phone1.png" width="100" height="100" id="phoneImg" class="contactImgs" data-toggle="popover" tabindex="50" data-content="test <b>text</b>" data-placement="right" />

.popover {
background-color: #f8be94;
border:none;
 }

.popover .arrow::before {
    background-color: #f8be94 !important;
}
```

I need to color the arrow entirely (border and background) in the color mentioned in my code...

Comment: the code provided is too limited. please add more

Comment: that's the code related to the popover style... I added the popover body style as well...